# Quotient of a smooth projective surface by an involution

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-surfaces

Is the quotient of a smooth complex projective surface by an involution projective? Suppose the quotient happens to be smooth; does that change the situation?

Comment: It should be true at least when the quotient $Y$ is smooth. To see this, first argue that the transcendence degree of the field of meromorphic functions $\mathbb{C}(Y)$ is 2, i.e. $Y$ is Moishezon. Then use a theorem of Chow-Kodaira to conclude $Y$ is projective.

Comment: The quotient of a projective variety by a finite group is always projective. This follows from the GIT: Let $X$ be a projective variety and $G$ a finite group acting on it. Let $L$ be a very ample $G$-linearized invertible sheaf on $X$ (which always exists as $G$ is a linear reductive group). As $G$ is finite, every point of $X$ is stable. So we have a geometric quotient $X = X^s \to \mathrm{Proj}\bigoplus_{k \ge 0} H^0(X,L^{\otimes k})^G$ of $X$ by $G$. As $X$ is projective, the target $X/G$ is also projective.

Comment: @HYL: Are you sure this is true in general? Doesn't Hironaka's example give a counter-example for 3-folds? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hironaka%27s_example

Comment: Anyway, I agree the result should hold for surfaces.

Comment: @DanielLoughran. The argument by  HYL is correct.  Here is the elementary argument without GIT notation.  For any ample invertible sheaf $L$ and any  finite self-map $f$ of $X$, also $f^*L$ is ample.  Any tensor product of ample invertible sheaves is ample, thus the tensor product $M$ of all pullbacks $f^*L$ over all elements $f$ of $G$ is ample and $G$-equivariant.  For every $G$-invariant invertible sheaf $M$, for all sufficiently positive and divisible $n$, the invertible sheaf $M^{\otimes n}$ descends.  Finally, by Chevalley, the descent invertible sheaf is ample.

Comment: @DanielLoughran In Hironaka's example the variety quotiented by a finite group is not projective -- read the Wikipedia page you linked.

Comment: @Kevin Casto: I'm not sure why you are telling me to read something which I have already read and has already been clarified in the comments. Anyway, Hironaka's example is much worse than you state; it gives a proper (non-projective) variety $X$ such that finite quotient $X/G$ is an algebraic space, but not a scheme.

Answer (score 2):

The quotient of a quasi-projective variety $X$ by a finite group action $G$ is quasi-projective. As is explained in [1, Remarque V.5.1], this  follows from [1, Theoreme V.4.1].

[1] M. Demazure and A. Grothendieck. Schémas en groupes I, II, III (SGA 3). Lecture
Notes in Math. 151, 152, 153. Springer-Verlag, New York, 1970